# Trying configure Websocket endpoint with Java 11, OpenJSK, Apache Tomcat/8.5.41

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Im trying to configure Websockets on my tomcat server but I'm not able to set the endpoint. But I keep getting error

```
error: cannot find symbol @ServerEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")
```

I installed the javax.websocket api but im still missing javax.websocket.server package. I've tried installing every java websocket package I could find and still doesnt work.

Is it supposed to be a part of my tomcat server, java 11 or openJDK, or do I just have to get from somewhere online? I've not been able to find this package till now. All other anotations work when I compile with websocket-api.jar

```
import javax.naming.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.websocket.*;



@ServerEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")
public class OffisEndpoint{

    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message){
        try{
            if(this.session != null && this.session.isOpen()){
                this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText("From Server"+ message);
    
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){
        System.out.println("Close Connection ...");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you compiling?  You'll want something like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to assist with dependency management.

Comment: I'm just manually compiling using javac -cp /path/to/websocket-api className.java

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to live without a build tool very long as you move forward.  For this code I used [maven](https://maven.apache.org) to get going.  Maven assumes a particular directory structure so your environment would look like:

```
pom.xml
src/
  main/
    java/
      com/
        example/
          websocket/
            OffisEndpoint.java
```

The first line in `OffisEndpoint.java` will now be `package com.example.websocket;` to indicate that the file now lives in a Java package.

The contents of `pom.xml` are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

You'll need to install Maven to be able to use it.  See the [Install instructions](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) for more detail.

Once you get Maven installed, change to the directory where your `pom.xml` file lives and run `mvn clean package`.  This will download files that are needed one time.  The next time you build it will not take very long.

The build creates `target/websocket-1.0.0.war`.  This can be deployed to a running Tomcat by copying it to the `webapps` directory.

You will access this websocket endpoint through `http://localhost:8080/websocket/websocketendpoint`.  The extra path element is because your code is deploy the the `websocket` web application.

Comment: Find a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/achimmihca/tomcat-websocket-example)